# Kentico 11 - How to make the search Dialog inside an Uni Selector search for other than name

Tags: kentico

I have a situation with a custom user interface where I need to use an UniSelector-type component but the displayed names of the objects would be composite, e.g: 'ClientPrefix + " - " + ClientName'.

This would be trivial to do by creating a macro on the DisplayName property of the selector, however, if the client uses the search dialog he's not able to search by the Prefix part of the objects.

I know that an UniSelector component uses the "selectall" query so I tried using a view there to bring a new "ClientCodeName" column with the final name and it works properly in place of the macro above, however the search still ignores it and searches by name only.

There doesn't seem to exist a property for this on Kentico. Is there a way to modify this behaviour? I 
would be fine creating a custom unigrid implementation if it would come to this, as long as I can still keep the solution as a Custom module interface.

[If client searches for 1401, nothing comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LKdx.png)

Comment: Hi @Thiago, I'm not sure I fully understand your question. What I would ask is what properties you have registered for search on the `Client` object and also how you have defined your search index.  Also, can you confirm if you are using SmartSearch, or Azure Search?

Comment: Hello @mnield ! Sorry I wasn't very clear. It's neither one in this case, it's just the search dialog window inside the default UniSelector component. It seems to always use the "Name" property of the class regardless of any properties on the Uniselector itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a field under the advanced options of the uni selector called "Additional columns". Add the columns to this that you want to have it also search through.